# Recording slamming doors?

Tags: recording, frequency-response

I'm a complete novice hoping for someone to point me in the right direction.

I'm looking for (hopefully) a handheld recorder to record assorted banging (primarily slamming doors) from next door.

Obviously I don't need anything to capture production level sound, just something with enough of a low end frequency response(?) to capture the noise as evidence.

I was looking at the Tascam DR-40, would that do the job, is there a better product for similar money or would I need a separate microphone/recorder setup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds just like my neighbours ;) They also appear to communicate by barking at each other - yet no actual canines live there. More seriously, getting extended bottom-end needs something fabulously flat, like a DPA [B&K] 4006 or some of the Earthworks [can't remember numbers] which to my ear over-emphasis the bottom, but cleanly. The recorder can only record what the mic hands it.

Comment: I did some testing of a recorder I have before and posted it here, but I'm sorry I can't do it now or my neighbours (and then my landlord) would kill me :D

Comment: The quality of recording is not going to matter much in this scenario. Instead you should focus on making the recording useful by setting references. Set the device in a reasonable spot (like next to your couch or bed) and record yourself speaking next to it and then next to the wall. After that, don't move it and wait to record the door slamming.